# YouTube Search Result Scraper

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, youtube

This is a program I wrote in Python using the BeautifulSoup library. The program scrapes YouTube search results for a given query and extracts data from the channels returned in the search results.

I'm just looking for some tips on how to make my code look (and function) better. I removed most of the redundancies but to me the code still feels ugly.

Suggestions?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/
# http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

import csv
import re
import requests
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# scrapes the title 
def getTitle():
    d = soup.find_all("h1", "branded-page-header-title")
    for i in d:
        name = i.text.strip().replace('\n',' ').replace(',','').encode("utf-8")
        f.write(name+',')
        print('\t\t%s') % (name)

# scrapes the subscriber and view count
def getStats():
    b = soup.find_all("li", "about-stat ") # trailing space is required.
    for i in b:
        value = i.b.text.strip().replace(',','')
        name = i.b.next_sibling.strip().replace(',','')
        f.write(value+',')
        print('\t\t%s = %s') % (name, value)

# scrapes the description
def getDescription():
    c = soup.find_all("div", "about-description")
    for i in c:
        description = i.text.strip().replace('\n',' ').replace(',','').encode("utf-8")
        f.write(description+',')
        #print('\t\t%s') % (description)

# scrapes all the external links 
def getLinks():
    a = soup.find_all("a", "about-channel-link ") # trailing space is required.
    for i in a:
        url = i.get('href')
        f.write(url+',')
        print('\t\t%s') % (url)

# scrapes the related channels
def getRelated():
    s = soup.find_all("h3", "yt-lockup-title")
    for i in s:
        t = i.find_all(href=re.compile("user"))
        for i in t:
            url = 'https://www.youtube.com'+i.get('href')
            rCSV.write(url+'\n')
            print('\t\t%s,%s') % (i.text, url)  

f = open("youtube-scrape-data.csv", "w+")
rCSV = open("related-channels.csv", "w+")
visited = []
base = "https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query="
q = ['search+query+here']
page = "&page="
count = 1
pagesToScrape = 20

for query in q:
    while count <= pagesToScrape:
        scrapeURL = base + str(query) + page + str(count)
        print('Scraping %s\n') %(scrapeURL)
        r = requests.get(scrapeURL)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
        users = soup.find_all("div", "yt-lockup-byline")
        for each in users:
            a = each.find_all(href=re.compile("user"))
            for i in a:
                url = 'https://www.youtube.com'+i.get('href')+'/about'
                if url in visited:
                    print('\t%s has already been scraped\n\n') %(url)
                else:
                    r = requests.get(url)
                    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
                    f.write(url+',')
                    print('\t%s') % (url)
                    getTitle()
                    getStats()
                    getDescription()
                    getLinks()
                    getRelated()
                    f.write('\n')   
                    print('\n')
                    visited.append(url)
                    time.sleep(3)
        count += 1  
        time.sleep(3)
        print('\n')
    count = 1
    print('\n') 
f.close()
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty much a n00b to programming myself, so take my advice with a grain of salt... but I would try making each of your "get..." functions into a method of a class (let's say `YoutubeVid`). It's `__init__` would set all the attributes at once, without printing. A seperate function, let's say `print_attributes` could do the printing. Once you code that part, you would replace this:

```
            else:
                r = requests.get(url)
                soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
                f.write(url+',')
                print('\t%s') % (url)
                getTitle()
                getStats()
                getDescription()
                getLinks()
                getRelated()
                f.write('\n')   
                print('\n')
                visited.append(url)
                time.sleep(3)
```

With something like this:

```
            else:
                r = requests.get(url)
                soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
                video_page = YoutubeVid(soup)
                print_attributes(video_page)
```

I'm sorry I don't have the time to work out a more detailed example, but if that makes any sense to you, maybe you can give it a try and post what you come up with.

Also, a minor detail regarding function names... Mixed case like `getTitle()` is depricated. Lowercase with underscores like `get_title()` is prefered. [See the PEP Style Guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-names).

Answer (score 3):

#### Code Style

There are multiple [PEP8 code style](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) violations, some of them are:

- naming - use `lower_case_with_underscores` naming style
- [spaces around operators](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#whitespace-in-expressions-and-statements)
- [blank lines between imports and functions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#blank-lines)

You should also improve your variable naming - for example, `d`, `b`, `i` are not meaningful - think of more descriptive names - remember: **Code is much more often read than written**.

#### HTML-parsing and Web-scraping

- instantiate [`requests.Session()`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects) and reuse to make requests - this would give you a performance boost "for free":

  > if you're making several requests to the same host, the underlying TCP connection will be reused, which can result in a significant performance increase
- you can replace `.find_all()` calls with more explicit and robust [`select()` calls and use CSS selectors](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors). For instance, `soup.find_all("h1", "branded-page-header-title")` would become `soup.select("h1.branded-page-header-title")`
- it is also a good idea to [specify a parse that `BeautifulSoup` uses under-the-hood explicitly](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#specifying-the-parser-to-use):

  ```
  soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")  # built-in, no extra dependencies
  # soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")  # the fastest
  # soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html5lib")  # the most lenient
  ```

#### Other

- use [`with` context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) when dealing with file-like objects
- either remove the unused `csv` import or use it to write the results into CSV files
- convert comments before the functions into *proper docstrings*